# How to set path to the file location in the "CSV Data Set Config" if csv.file is located in bitbucket

Tags: jmeter

I want to run Jmeter project in Jenkins. I commited project.jmx and related csv files in bitbucket. How can I set the path to the csv file located in bitbucket

Answer (score 12):

CSV Data Set config will accept

- Absolute path (the complete path like c:\path\to\csv\file.csv)
- Relative path from the test (csvfolder\csvfile.csv)

  ```
  csvfolder
       csvfile.csv
  .jmx
  ```

  Assuming the 'csvfolder' folder is present where you have .jmx

If your folder structure is as given below,

```
csvfolder
   csvfile
jmxfolder
   jmx
```

then your CSV file path should be `../csvfolder/csvfile`

Comment: This is incorrect. When used as absolute path like c:\path\to\csv\file.csv JMETER errors out with the message: unexpected char: '\'

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming The absolute path needs / instead of \

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about you specific combination, but usually if your files are in the same location you can refer to them by name only.

Let's say

```
%JMETER_HOME%\jmeter -n -t %LOAD_TESTS_RUNNER_%/_warmup.jmx 
-Jusers=1 -Jrampup=5 -Jloop=2 -JpathToToken=Token.txt
```

Token.txt is just located in the same directory as *.jmx file.

Optionally, you could use system variables to contain your paths.

Comment: I would be happy to use something like this ../Data/UpdateList_Success.csv in Filepath . But it does not work

Comment: 1. Ensure 'Data' folder exists; 2. path=Data/UpdateList_Success.csv

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Bitbucket underlying repository type you can configure Jenkins job to be triggered by commit using

- [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)
- [Jenkins Mercurial Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin)

So you will be able to refer paths to JMeter .jmx and .csv files just using their names. Or if you prefer full paths - you can use `WORKSPACE` Jenkins variable like:

- `%WORKSPACE%` - for MS Windows Family
- `$WORKSPACE`  - for Linux/Unix/MacOSX

See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for more information on running JMeter tests from Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

How to read data from CSV File and run jmx for linux

If my jmx file is login.jmx
my input file is   users.csv

what should be the syntax or command in linux

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31238284)